# Confirm who is sending data to our Marketing Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, api, dataextensions, triggered-send, source

So I inherited a business unit in Marketing Cloud, and we have one triggered email whose data source I can't locate. Is there a way to confirm all the data sources/APIs that are connecting to a particular marketing cloud instance?

Comment: Unfortunately not - have you looked at the email itself, maybe it will give you a clue about the purpose it’s used for? You could also try inspecting the tracking data and SendLog or Triggered Send Data Extension if they have been set up, to try to figure out how the data that gets sent is used..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the other user mentioned, you cannot see this information directly. One other place to check would be the Installed Packages. 
Go to Setup > Platform Tools > Apps > Installed Packages
If there are only a few integrations and/or some good naming conventions used, this could help your search. 
Here's some information about what exactly you will be looking at: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-app-development.meta/mc-app-development/api-integration.htm